# Is it possible to delete a folder from a eclipse.ini file?

Tags: java, eclipse

I have searched many links, can anybody let me know if it's possible to delete a complete folder by mentioning the location of the folder in the eclipse.ini file?

I checked this link, but couldn't find anything conclusive.

http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/misc/runtime-options.html

Example: Can I do something like

-launcher.deleteFolder
C:/xyz/xxx

in eclipse.ini file ?

Comment: Why would you want to do that? If I may ask.

Comment: Hello George, insight is that, we are using Eclipse RCP Framework, so some of the workbench preferences while opening the client application are stored under a separate folder called 'config'. Sometimes it throws some unusual workbench error, we manually delete the 'config' folder and then restart the workbench, it works absolutely fine then, so if at all I want to automate this process or I mean everytime the config folder is refreshed while I start the workbench wouldnt be a solution ?, FYI all this is done through .ini file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have several options.

Insert `-clean` argument in the `eclipse.ini` file

Hook a shell or batch script to the `eclipse.exe` that deletes the specified files

Insert `-clean` argument on the `eclipse.exe` shortcut

The RCP Framework stores configuration detail in two ways: either `"something".prefs` OR `"something".xml` (can't remember the exact file names). Clearing these files can be done from within the source code.

Personally, I would go with the `batch` version; but the cleanest and most stylish method is clearing from source code.

Please leave a comment if any of these suggestions helped you in any way.

Comment: I did the batch file atlast, it was okay and client accepted it :)